How to use file data with newman and Postman url with uuid
I have a Postman test with a png file uploaded in the body in Postman cloud.
Running from Postman web or App is working fine.
I get my Postman test uuid and environment uuid with:
curl -X 'GET' https://api.getpostman.com/collections?apikey=PMAK-665e1....
curl -X 'GET' https://api.getpostman.com/environments?apikey=PMAK-665e....

Then I try to run with Newman with this command :
newman run "https://api.getpostman.com/collections/333976...?apikey=PMAK-665e1..." --environment "https://api.getpostman.com/environments/333976...?apikey=PMAK-665e1..."

but it doesn't work, it seems that Newman can not get the file from Postman cloud to test? do you confirm? do we have another solution to use Postman uuid url and png,pdf,docx file (not json or csv with -d option) upload with Newman?
But I tried another method by running the Postman and environment json files locally and I change the path to the file locally
{
   "key": "file_in",
   "contentType": "image/png",
   "type": "file",
   "src": "TEST.png"
},

and it works fine:
newman run Tests.postman_collection.json -e DEV.postman_environment.json    


https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/create-requests/test-data/#about-test-data-storage

To enable sharing requests that use test data files, you can upload
the files to your Postman team. Uploaded files are available to all
members of your team and can be used to send requests that are shared
in a workspace. Uploaded files are also available to requests sent
from monitors and scheduled collection runs, and can be used from
Postman Flows and the Postman CLI (but not Newman).

This will not work when running these with Newman. Have you tried the same thing using the Postman CLI?
